# Packaging bash script with dh-make

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, packaging, dh-make

I have installed dh-make by installing other packages as recommended by [this page](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html) which depend on it (I am listing all packages which could have installed it as well because I am not certain which one did):

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg pbuilder ubuntu-dev-tools bzr-builddeb apt-file
```

And run it with:

```
dh_make
```

In the directory where my folder is located containing my bash script (the folder's name is based on the template `<packagename>-<version>`), but now it is giving me these options:

```
Type of package: single binary, indep binary, multiple binary, library, kernel module, kernel patch?
 [s/i/m/l/k/n]
```

As I am packaging a bash script, which one do I choose if any? And what do they all mean?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
dh-make:
  Installed: 1.20140617
  Candidate: 1.20140617
  Version table:
 *** 1.20140617 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descriptions of the options are all given in [`man dh_make`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dh_make.8):

```
   Single binary (s)
          The package will generate a single binary .deb  package.  It  is
          the standard case, so if you don't know what to do, choose this.

   Arch-Independent (i)
          The  package  will  generate  a  single  package  that  is arch-
          independent.

   Multiple binary (m)
          The package will generate multiple binary .deb packages from one
          source  package. Choose this for larger packages that need to be
          split.

   Library (l)
          The package will generate at least  two  binaries.  One  library
          package   containing  just  the  lib  in  /usr/lib  and  another
          *-dev_*.deb package containing documentation and C headers.

   Kernel module (k)
          The package will generate a  binary-all  kernel  module  -source
          package for use with the make-kpkg(1) command. It also generates
          a binary package for additional utilities,  daemons,  etc.  that
          may come with the source.

   Kernel patch
          The  package will generate a package that can be used for kernel
          patches.
```

- For a single program, you would normally use `s`, but in your case, it is a shell script, which does not depend on the architecture of the target system, so **pick `i`**.
- For `m` (multiple binary), it would generate multiple packages (an example would be the various `vim` packages, which are all generated from the same source package).